# I need to prove that if X ~ Geometric (theta) then...

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $X \sim \mathrm{Geometric}(\theta)$, then prove $P(X=n+m \mid X>n)=P(X= m)$

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the memoryless property of geometric random variables.

$$P(X=n+m|X>n) = \frac{P(X=n+m,X>n)}{P(X>n)}$$

$$= \frac{P(X=n+m)}{P(X>n)} = \frac{(1-\theta)^{m+n-1}\theta}{(1-\theta)^n}= (1-\theta)^{m-1}\theta = P(X=m)$$
Note that I have not used the memoryless property here. Rather this proves it holds.